# Change the default colors of mdl-textfield

Tags: angular2-mdl

I'm trying to change the color of mdl-textfield and its label:

```
<mdl-textfield
        label="E-mail"
        name="email"
        type="text"
        formControlName="email"
        floating-label  
        pattern="^[a-z]+[a-z0-9._]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z.]{2,5}$"
        error-msg="Prière de fournir une adrresse e-mail correcte!">
</mdl-textfield>
```

is there any way to do that witouth modifiying the main css file: material.min.css.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular-cli and want the change the component's style globally, just add the CSS properties to the **style.css** file you will find in the **src** folder of your project:

```
{
  "project": {
   ...
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      ...
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ]
      ...
```

Note that in older versions of angular-cli this file may be called differently. Just have a look in your **angular-cli.json** file: in the **apps** property there should be a **styles** property defining an array of stylesheets which will be applied globally.

Another way to change the styles, independent of angular-cli, depends which View Encapsulation mode you use. Per default Angular 2 uses 'Emulated', which scopes the CSS to a single component. If you want to override the textfield's style in just one component, do so by setting the according style property:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: require('./template_my-component.html'),
  styles: ['mdl-textield { color: red; ...}']
})
```

If you want to override it's style globally, you can set View Encapsulation to None, which prevents the CSS being scoped but applied globally. Make sure to import **ViewEncapsulation**.

```
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-component',
      template: require('./template_my-component.html'),
      styles: ['mdl-textield { color: red; ...}'],
      encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
    })
```

But take care, as this could end up in a mess if you start to set different properties for the same elements in different files.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this

Comment: really, I did not test this. However I did change my global css file that i downloaded from :
http://mseemann.io/angular2-mdl/theme

You can find the associated css class and modify the color there!

Hope that this help,

Regards